# How do I get the "user_id" for a customer places an order?

Tags: php

I have been struggling with this for a while now. Is there any way for me to get the "user_id" form my "users" table into my "orders" table when a customer places an order?

When using the second SQL statement, after the "INSERT INTO" statement, the system still says that the order has been successful. However, when I check my database the order has not even been inserted.

Without the use of the second SQL statement the order will be inserted correctly, with every field except the "user_id" being placed in the table.

I have also tried "INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...) SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... FROM table1 WHERE condition;" Statement and that also does not work.

Would it work if only one SQL command was written? If so I am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';


$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['type']);
$square_ft = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['square_ft']);
$materials = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['materials']);
$time= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time']);    
$date= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['date']);
$price= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['price']);




if (empty($price) || empty($time) || empty($date) || empty($type) || empty($square_ft) || empty($materials)) {
        header("Location: ../placeorder.php?order=empty");
        exit();
    } else {

    //Insert orders into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (price, time, date, type,   square_ft, materials,) VALUES('$price', '$time', '$date', '$type', '$square_ft','$materials');";
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (user_id) FROM users;";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location: ../orderform.php?order=success");
exit();

} 
}
?>

<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: dude, you're overriding the `$sql` variable. And it's a weird query anyway; insert _what_ user id? Besides; `INSERT ... FROM` will fail; it's not valid. You mean something like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT user_id FROM ...` But even better; you ought to know the user id beforehand, so you don't need two queries, just insert the user id in the first one

Comment: Sorry I'm a completely novice programmer and this is my first ever "major" project. Would it be better if I fetched the "user_id" for that specific user earlier in the code?

Comment: well, assuming the user has to be logged in; you already know the user id, as you'll be checking authentication somewhere. If you create a new user while processing the order; create the user first, then use that id to insert into the orders table

Comment: Thank you! It is working now. I greatly appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

To get key from Users, you need to perform `SELECT` over users field, then to insert users key into orders. It would be something like this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT user_id FROM users_table WHERE username='someusername'";
$userid = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, $sql1));     

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO orders (price, time, date, type,   square_ft, materials, user_id) VALUES('$price', '$time', '$date', '$type', '$square_ft','$materials', '$userid');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
```

Comment: now you're inserting the `order_id` as the `user_id`... AND you're creating a whole new order, while only the user id ought to be updated

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that